# Error with: npm run dev

Tags: laravel

> @ dev /home/eduardo/blog2
>   npm run development
>
> @ development /home/eduardo/blog2
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/eduardo/blog2/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'npm run development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

This is the error im getting while trying to install npm on laravel.

I already installed node and yarn, any help?

Comment: Is it possible to install a package with yarn and run with npm?

Comment: You can delete the node_modules directory, and run `npm install` then `npm run dev`

Comment: I already tried that, and it failed.. but i found the source of the problem, i needed libpng-dev

Answer (score 1):

You are not installing npm. You are trying to run `npm run development` and get `cross-env: not found` error. Looks like you just need to install it with `npm install --save-dev cross-env`

Comment: i already installed npm, but will try with those arguments to see if it works

Still doesnt work:(

Answer (score 0):

Try using npm instal npm and then trying the code again :B

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).